# How do I change the formatting of the license agreement in a dmg file using CPack?

Tags: macos, installation, cmake, cpack, dmg

I am using CPack to create a dmg file for installation on MacOS. Because I have provided `CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE` the license file is included in the dmg file and a window is opened when trying to mount it. After clicking "Agree", I can drag and drop my application to install.

However, the license file looks very ugly. It's displayed as plain text, double line breaks are condensed into one and there are seemingly random line breaks in the middle of the text. I would really like to improve the look.

Ideally, there is an CPack-compatible way to change the formatting, font, font size, etc. But if not, then I would be content with a way to add an empty line between paragraphs.

I have tried adding more line breaks, but any number of line breaks get condensed into one.

This is what the license file looks like:

```
MIT License

Copyright (c) 2020-2022

Permission is hereby granted, free ...
```

[image: The line breaks here are due to line breaks in the original license file, but even when I remove those, new line breaks inexplicably appear.]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution for my problem. It is possible to create a rich text version of the license file, and make CPack use that one instead. That way, it's easily possible to format the license agreement using TextEdit.

I have not experimented with changing the font, font size, and font weights, but using rtf allowed me to display the license agreement justified and with double line breaks between paragraphs.